Is this approach to prove $xe^{\alpha (1-x)}+(1-x)e^{-\alpha x}\leq e^{\alpha^{2}/2}$, for $x\in[0,1]$ and $\alpha>0$, in the "correct" path?

If $x \in [0,1]$ and $\alpha > 0$ , then show $$xe^{\alpha (1-x)}+(1-x)e^{-\alpha x}\;\leq\; e^{\alpha^{2}/2}$$

I derived the LHS and in deed found a maximum $x=\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{e^{\alpha}-1}$, but when it was put back to the original equation it turned into an overwhelming expression to deal with. I am not sure if its supposed to continue thereon or if I am missing some clear simplification.

@JeanMarie That's not correct, it is true for all $\alpha$, even negative.

Firstly, note that for $\alpha > 2$, $e^{\alpha (1-x)} \leq e^{\alpha^2/2}$ and $e^{-\alpha x} \leq e^{\alpha x} \leq e^{\alpha^2/2}$. Thus, the inequality immediately holds. We can focus only on the case where $0 < \alpha \leq 2$. For this case, note that $e^{\alpha x} \leq 1 + \alpha x + 2 \alpha^2 x^2$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. Since both $e^{\alpha x}$ and $1 + \alpha x + 2 \alpha^2 x^2$ are monotonoically increasing functions for $x > 0$, they can intersect only once for $x > 0$. It is straightforward to note that $e^{\alpha x} < 1 + \alpha x + 2 \alpha^2 x^2$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ and $x = 1$. Thus, throughout the interval $[0,1]$,  $e^{\alpha x} \leq 1 + \alpha x + 2 \alpha^2 x^2$. For $x \leq 0$, it is well known that $e^{\alpha x} \leq 1 + \alpha x +  \frac{\alpha^2 x^2}{2} \leq 1 + \alpha x +  2\alpha^2 x^2$. Thus, we have $e^{\alpha x} \leq 1 + \alpha x + 2 \alpha^2 x^2$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
xe^{\alpha(1-x)} + (1-x)e^{-\alpha x} & \leq x (1 + \alpha(1-x) + 2\alpha^2(1-x)^2) + (1-x)(1 - \alpha x + 2\alpha^2 x^2) \\
& \leq 1 + 2\alpha^2x(1-x) \\
& \leq 1 + \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \\
& \leq e^{\alpha^2/2}.
\end{align*}
In the third line we used $x(1-x) \leq 1/4$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and in the fourth line we used $1 + x \leq e^x$ for all $x$.

Great! Could you just share your line of thought that lead you to come up with specifically the expression $1+\alpha x + 2 \alpha^2x^2$. I am trying to do some reverse engineering to figure out how you foresaw all that substitution and fall exactly at $1+\alpha^2/2$

The first thing was symmetry noting that the first order terms will definitely cancel out. Figuring out the 2$\alpha^2 x^2$ instead of $\alpha^2 x^2/2$ was a little bit of trying around. It had to be greater than $1$ and I needed just enough to ensure it holds for $\alpha \leq 2$. Also, this is not the tightest bound, you can make the term $1.1 \alpha^2 x^2$.  However, the main idea is to note that sometimes the series expansion is a great tool for inequalities with $e^x$ as differentiation does not yield nice analytical expressions.
